# How to get user input and output it onto the web page

Tags: javascript, input, output

I am trying to create a program where I ask the user for two numeric inputs and then output to the web page the value of those two numbers when added together (show something like 1 + 2 = 3) and then display those two numbers multiplied together (1 * 2 = 2). Sample output should look something like the following but based on the input received from the website user:

1 + 2 = 3

1 * 2 = 2

Comment: Any code? What have you tried?

Comment: You should show that you already tried something so we don't end up giving you a "free" solution to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `prompt` like so:

```js
var number1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
var number2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter another number"));

document.write(`${number1} + ${number2} = ${number1 + number2}<br>${number1} * ${number2} = ${number1 * number2}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use input tag for taking inputs and .innerHTML for outputting to the html

```js
function a() {
  document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = Number(document.getElementById("a").value) + Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a" />
<input type="number" id="b" onkeyup="a()" />
<div id="c"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function submit() {
   let test =document.getElementById("text");
   let sum = parseFloat(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value) +parseFloat(document.getElementById("lastNumber").value);
    let mul = parseFloat(document.getElementById("firstNumber").value)  * parseFloat(document.getElementById("lastNumber").value);
   test.innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value + ' + ' +document.getElementById("lastNumber").value + " = " +sum +" </br>";
    test.innerHTML += document.getElementById("firstNumber").value + ' * ' +document.getElementById("lastNumber").value + " = " + mul +"\n";
   return true;
}
```

```html
  First number:<br>
  <input type="number" id="firstNumber" >
  <br>
  Last number:<br>
  <input type="number" id="lastNumber" >
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="return submit();">click</button>


<div id="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that may be more familiar to your level of programming, In this case we have input fields instead of prompts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    function calc(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById("in1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("in2").value;
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = num1 + "+" + num2 + "=" + (parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2));
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <input id="in1" type="number"/>
  <input id="in2" type="number"/>

  <button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
  <p></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

since it wasnt stated i want to assume, you are asking for the numbers whe the user visits the page, and i'm receiving these inputs via prompt requests...

```
<script>

function init(){
  var input1 = prompt("Please enter the first Number", "First Number");
  var input2 = prompt("Please enter the second Number", "Second Number");

   if (input1 != null && input2 != null) {

     sum = parseInt(input1) + parseInt(input2); 
     str1 = input1 + " + " + input2 + " = " + sum;

     multi = parseInt(input1) * parseInt(input2);
     str2 = input1 + " * " + input2 + " = " + multi;

     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = str1 + "<br/>" + str2;

    }else{
       alert('...error message');
    }

   }  //end of function...

</script>


<body onload="init()">
  ......    
  <div id="message"></div>
</body>
```

that should work, as expected ...